# Find the Laurent series of the function in the given domain

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series for the function $$f(z) = 1/(z+z²)$$ in the given domains:
$$\begin{align}&(a)\space\space 0<abs(z)<1\\ 
&(b)\space\space 1< abs(z)\\ 
&(c)\space\space 0<abs(z+1)<1\\ 
&(d)\space\space 1< abs(z+1)\end{align}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial.  Where did you find this problem?  What have you tried?  What do you know that might help?